# noVNC Mouse Pointer not visible in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer

I have noVNC downloaded from

https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.git (master)

I am trying to use noVNC via Internet Explorer 11, but I cannot see the mouse pointer.

However I verified that noVNC works perfectly alright via google chrome and mozilla firefox.

Any help or hints appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that IE 11 does not display local cursor, hence we got to display remote cursor.

For rest of the browser, we can use local cursor